# Application Window and Dialog Issue in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am not able to click on the `VirtualKeyboard` if the `TextField` is in the dialog and `Application Window` is the base class.

Following is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id:appwindow
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Button{
        id:button
        text:qsTr("Open")
        onClicked:{
            dialog.visible=true
            dialog.open()
        }
    }

    Dialog{
        id:dialog
        width:200
        height:300
        visible:false
        TextField {
            id: textfield
            color: "#2B2C2E"
        }
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 89
        anchors.bottom:parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        visible: Qt.inputMethod.visible 
    }
}
```

There will be no issues if I change **ApplicationWindow** to **Window**, Is that a QT Bug in **v5.9.1**?

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56918 might be related.

Comment: I did the same, That is not working !!!

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationWindow`  offers a nice extra layer `overlay` to which you may reparent everything that shall be above the rest of the content - just the right place for your `VirtualKeyboard`

```
InputPanel {
    id: inputPanel
    parent: ApplicationWindow.overlay // <-- This will do the trick
    anchors.bottom:parent.bottom
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    visible: Qt.inputMethod.visible
}
```

Comment: You are right. It only works with `Popup`s in *Qt5.7* - in the newer *Qt5.9* it will fail again.

Comment: Someone should raise a bug on this .Can you raise?

Comment: It not working on Qt 6.3.0 and Qt 6.6.1 :/